# how to capture javascript request payload in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending a request payload from a javascript function like such

```js
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      fetch('https://www.eg.com/tq.php', {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          orderID: id // i get the id here.
        })
      });
      return window.location.href = "https://www.https://www.eg.com/tq.php";
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

In my PHP file I want to retrieve that id. I did :

```php
$data = $_POST['orderID'];
```

AND

```php
$data = json_decode($data); 
echo $data->orderID;
```

AND

even tried changing the url to x-www-form-urlencoded. Still I do not get the value. When I check on the payload I do see the orderID, I also see a 200 OK. Can someone show me what i'm doing wrong? I did research stackoverflow and still can't get this to work. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

`fetch` function will send `GET` request if you don't pass `method: POST` in config explicitly. 
That's why you're not getting `orderID` from `$_POST` in server-side.

Insert `method: "POST"` in config like this.

```
fetch("https://www.eg.com/tq.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    orderID: id // i get the id here.
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi, even with a "POST" method i'm not getting any response

Comment: Hi @MohitPaudyal, try to print out whole post param by `var_dump($_POST)` in server-side.